# Android app that accesses database on server machine

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm developing an android app that accesses Databases that are stored on a server machine. I've done a bit a of googling and had a look through some of my programming books but can't find much information.

SQLite seems like the right way to go but I can't find anything about Databases stored on a server. I'd appreciate it if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of server you are talking about?

The simplest case is that you can write a server program to expose some information in your database. Then, you can do a GET request from your Android app to get those data.
If data is more complicated and structural, your server can return json or xml object, then parse them from your client.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that as the data isn't that complicated but I thought that it might cause performance issues as it will need to be constantly sending/receiving data to server program.

Comment: If the result is the same most of the time, you can apply caching mechanism such as memcache to reduce database query

Comment: The result will be completely depended on user and could be the same most of the time but then again it could be completely different all the time. But you've given me an idea that I'm going to try out. tTanks!